# Filter in view with some dynamic value

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type, have a integer value field suppose field name is "field_xyz" and I have also variable from variable tables (variable_set('xyz')) which have some dynamic value

Now I want to create a view in which I need to add a filter and showing all node having field_xyz's value greater than equal to variable_get('xyz') value. I can do this using views_php module but I want to do it with manual configuration (No PHP code). Is there anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend [`views_php`](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module. This will hamper performance of the site.

You can use [`hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x) for this. What you have to do is - add `field_xyz` filter inside view, and override it in `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`.

Comment: Thanks Subhojit777 for your help But I need something do it by contrib module I don't want to do by custom code

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use custom code? Drupal provides it's own API so that we can build something that is not available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 extra modules installed: [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) and [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472)

You need to install the sub-module of Variable called **Variable views**

> Provides views integration for variable, included a default variable
>   argument.

Via it you can add a default value to the contextual filter as a Variable.

As you want to do a `value greater than equal to` comparison you will need the **Views arguments in filters** module:

> Using the "Views arguments in filters" module, you can use
>   placeholders when configuring filters, like so:
>
> - Node: Title CONTAINS %1
> - Node: Post date >= %2